# Can somebody explain the scope issue I have with this Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

I have some Javascript which mostly works except this one function which I can call from some areas but not others.  It appears to be a scope issue but I don't know why.

```
$().ready(function () {
   UpdateElfDisplay(); // <--- Undefined

   $('#Attribute1').change(function () {
      UpdateElfDisplay();  // <--- Works just fine.
   });

   var UpdateElfDisplay = function () {
      // ... some work done here 
   };
 });
```

As I marked above, the UpdateElfDisplay function works fine when I call it from .change() function but I get an "undefined" if I try to call it when the document is loaded.  Can somebody explain why, or direct me to a resource describing this.

Comment: Try moving the UpdateElfDisplay function declaration before your first call.

Comment: @epascarello - Hmm. I can see why some people might consider this a duplicate question because it now looks like the answers are the same. However, I think the question is sufficiently different. For example, "What color is the sky?" and "What color is the ocean?" might have the same answer but aren't duplicate questions.

Comment: It is the same answer, just different ways to ask it. lol

Comment: Yes. I guess I'm saying the ultimate question and answer are the same, but the question didn't seem the same to me until I saw the answer... if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling the function before it's defined, so it doesn't work. The one in the handler is invoked later, so it works

If you use a function declaration, it'll be "hoisted" and will work.

```
function UpdateElfDisplay () {
  // ... some work done here 
}
```

The JavaScript interpreter evaluates the declaration form of functions before any expressions are evaluated.

---

***Side note***

The reason it's a *TypeError* and not a *ReferenceError* is that the `var UpdateElfDisplay` is actually hoisted similar to the function declaration, but the *assignment* itself is not hoisted.

This means the variable exists, but it doesn't yet have your assigned value.

---

***Side note 2***

Your handler could probably be rewritten like this:

```
$('#Attribute1').change(UpdateElfDisplay);
```

Comment: Well, there is actually more work going on the .change handler, I just abbreviated it to demonstrate my problem.  But you answer is very clear now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
var UpdateElfDisplay = function () {
```

Until this line, `UpdateElfDisplay` has not been iniitalized.

Comment: This answer is, of course, perfectly correct and I gave it a +1.  The selected answer had more helpful details.